# Should I use Lazy<T> in a controller where a class may not be used?

Tags: c#, class, controller, asp.net-mvc-5, lazy-initialization

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and have a question in regards to using lazy and lazy initialization.

The [Lazy Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation says:

> Use lazy initialization to defer the creation of a large or
>   resource-intensive object, or the execution of a resource-intensive
>   task, particularly when such creation or execution might not occur
>   during the lifetime of the program.

Here is my situation:

I have a controller that has a validation service class. This service class is only used when creating or editing a model object in the controller create or edit functions.

Should I use Lazy for this validation class? I am thinking maybe, because a user can browse to the Index, Details and Delete functions, and the validation service class will never be used. The validation class has over 900 lines of code.

Also, I have an exception service class that is used to display custom error pages when an error occurs. This exception class has 100 lines of code, and is only used when an exception occurs. If an exception does not occur, this class will not be used. Should I use Lazy for this exception class?

I am asking for advice as I have not used Lazy before, and I am not sure if Lazy should be used in the above two cases.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Can someone please explain if there are any reasons NOT to use Lazy in the above situation? Is Exception caching something that I need to worry about?

The Validation service class has a constructor that accepts an `IGenericMultipleRepository` object. This object is an interface that is used to access the repository, and I use this when unit testing. The Exception service class has a default constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely use the lazy initialization for the validation service. For the exception handler, you can go either way - exceptions are expected. The nice thing about lazy initialization is that your code is more responsive and uses fewer resources. The downside is to learn a new class. Once you've learned it, you can use in many places.

Answer (score 0):

Lines of code really has little to do with the run-time cost of instantiating a class. If there are no statics and your have an empty constructor it's going to be cheap to instantiate your validation or exception classes.

A more significant issue is that by using Lazy or instantiating them directly you will be tightly coupling your controller class to these service classes which will make it harder to test them in isolation.

Without seeing the code it's hard to say exactly but I suspect that you would be better off injecting each class into the controller using dependency injection (and having an interface for each).

With that approach you can test each class independently, you can substitute a mock for the validation and exception classes and you can reuse these classes next time you have a controller than needs one.

If a class is expensive to instantiate you can still use a dependency injection container but you might use a `Func<T>` dependency. See for example [Autofac](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html).

I should also add that classes that are expensive to instantiate are themselves generally a bad idea: constructors should not do significant work.